Why does the Rdson limit from a MOSFET’s SOA graph not match its output characteristics curve?
The datasheet for the IPG20N06S4L has an SOA curve that shows the minimum on resistance is 50mOhm, whereas its output characteristics curve shows that you can achieve a 21.27mOhm on resistance. How do I reconcile these two graphs?
I must misunderstand what at least one of these graphs is telling us. I’ll list what I think are my main points of understanding so it is easier to identify why I am confused:

The Rdson limit is a physical limit that is shown on the SOA curve – despite “S” in SOA meaning “Safe”, this is less about safely operating the device and more about what is actually physically possible – operating outside of this region would imply you are getting a lower on resistance from the device than is physically possible;
The output characteristics curve  shows us the electrical behaviour of the FET for various gate-source voltages, hence looking at the highest Vgs curve to determine minimum on resistance is sensible here;
On resistance in the ohmic region of the FET usually goes down with higher VGS for N channel enhancement mode FETs;
Both graphs are made with the same measurement or calculation assumptions;



The "5. Typical output characteristics" graph shows typical values, the "3 Safe operating area" graph shows it for worst case parameters of a device - as you rightly discovered, VGS parameter is not noted for that graph - I assume 4.5V, because the rDSonMax is 46 mOhm at VGS 4.5V and at ID = 10A on page 2 of the datasheet. (Even if the "Safe operating area graph" would be shown for VGS 10V, they should use rDSonMax of 27 mOhm and not rDSonTyp of 21 mOhm - values also from page 2).

Another difference: Graph 5 is for Tj (junction) and graph 3. is for Tc (case), so Tj is higher --> therefore rdsOn is also higher according to Fig. 8! Therefore the figure 3 is perhaps even for VGS 10V.

The safe operating area has to give numbers that are "reliable" rather than typical. I mean, if the data sheet gave typical values for the safe regions, 50% of the devices wouldn't be safe to operate at those limits.

I've not done myself any favours asking a question in the title that differs from the question in my body. The fact that they're showing worst case (and thus derated) values makes sense for the SOA. I guess what I wanted to know is how to make the connection between what they show in the SOA and the other parameters and graphs in the datasheet.

I'm one step closer - i've found this in they show that the Rdson limit is calcuated using the RDSon for a Vgs of 10V and working at the max junction temperature: https://community.infineon.com/t5/Knowledge-Base-Articles/How-to-read-the-SOA-curve-in-the-datasheet/ta-p/407140. Graph 8 in the datasheet I linked shows that at max junction temperature and Vgs=10V, you would expect about 38mOhm Rds, which is closer to the worst case 50mOhm assumed by the SOA limit line.

I'm not sure I follow where you are going with this.
